# Opening a vertical terminal in Vim 8.1

Tags: vim, vimrc

Vim 8.1 added the `:terminal` command, which opens up a new bash terminal as a split.  However, it always seems to be a horizontal split, and I prefer vertical splits.  Is there a way to open a terminal as a vertical split without using:

```
:vsp
:terminal
<c-w>j
:q
```

Alternatively, is there a way I could add it as a command in my *.vimrc*, like so:

`command Vterm :vsp | :terminal | <c-w>j | :q`

The command above chokes on trying to execute `<c-w>j`, opens a new vim split with the following:

> executing job failed: No such file or directory

Just having:

`command Vterm :vsp | :terminal`

Works fine, but leaves the original split.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the [`:vert[ical]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630913/1364288) [command modifier](https://medium.com/@danidiaz/vim-command-modifiers-532f6932b297):

```
:vert term
```

`:vertical` works with any command that splits a window, for example:

```
:vert copen
:vert help vert
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in neovim: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3192

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure about regular `vim`, but the help says the `++curwin` option doesn't split the current window.  So you should be able to do something like:

```
:vs|:term ++curwin
```

Or you could use Neovim and just do `:vs|:terminal` or `:vs term://bash` :)

Comment: terminal command which I want to run accepts multiple CLI arguments, is it possible to pass multiple argulemnts with this syntax? I tried `:vnew term://lein repl` but it doesnt seems to works!!!? Also, I want to run this vim command from my ftplugin vimrc

Answer (score 2):

For neovim, to open a vertical terminal, the following work:

- `:vnew term://bash`
- `:vsplit term://bash`
- `:vnew term://zsh`
- `:vsplit term://zsh`

More documentation can be found by using `:h :terminal` inside neovim.